# How to get the cellwidth when inside a tabularx environment

Tags: tabularx

When I start a `tabularx` environment like this:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXX}
```

Can I, from inside a cell, get the width of the cell (to be used with includegraphics, minipage or something similar)?

Like this:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXX}
bla &
\includegraphics[width=\cellwidth]{...} &
\begin{minipage}{\cellwidth}...\end{minipage}
\end{tabularx}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The width of a `X`-column is saved in `\TX@col@width`.  Define a user command and then you can access it in your table.  But it is much easier to use `\linewidth`.  Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter 
\newcommand\mytxcellwidth{\TX@col@width}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|X|X|}
  \hline
  bla & \rule{\linewidth}{1cm} & \\ \hline
  bla & \rule{\mytxcellwidth}{1cm} &
  \begin{minipage}{\mytxcellwidth}...\end{minipage}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: usually it is easier to use `\hsize` or `\linewidth`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks for the reminder.  Indeed easier and I forgot that somehow.

Answer (score 6):

You can normally use \linewidth (but the minipage doesn't make much sense here):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXX}
bla &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
&
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\lipsum[1]\end{minipage}%
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can easily learn it: just switch to Linux, MacOS or any other operating system where case makes a difference in file names ;-)